# how to get all known component at runtime

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get a list of all known component at runtime (I'm dynamically injecting component and I need to make sure they are not already in the app)

Is there an easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you considered using static properties holding instances on your components ?

Comment: yes that's my fallback solution but I'd prefer something cleaner

Comment: Why would that be dirty ?

Comment: static stuff are never a good idea most of time and I'd prefer to use whatever angular dev had think about if possible

Comment: static things are good at holding static things. AFAIK, there is no such (documented) API that does what you are looking for.

Comment: what do you mean by known components this https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#components?